# LineHeightFactor and LineSpace with Spannable

Tags: java, android, kotlin, spannablestring, spannable

I need to use an `EditText` with Span to customize the text. For my app, I need two parameters for my spans :

- Line space
- Line Height factor

I've tried to use the interface `LineHeightSpan`for the first param like that :

```kotlin
class LineSpaceSpan(private val space : Int) : LineHeightSpan {

        override fun chooseHeight(
                text: CharSequence?,
                start: Int,
                end: Int,
                spanstartv: Int,
                lineHeight: Int,
                fm: Paint.FontMetricsInt?) {

                fm?.apply {
                    descent += space
                    bottom += space
                }
        }   
}
```

But the result isn't really what I expect...

For `Line Height factor` I know there an XML attribute in `EditText`, but I need a different value for each line

Has anyone ever had these needs? Thank you for your help!

**EDIT: More infos**

I've tried to solve my problem with `LineHeightSpan` like above with that code :

```kotlin
class LineSpaceSpan(private var lineRatio: Float, private var space : Int) : LineHeightSpan {

        override fun chooseHeight(
                text: CharSequence?,
                start: Int,
                end: Int,
                spanstartv: Int,
                lineHeight: Int,
                fm: Paint.FontMetricsInt?) {

                fm?.apply {

                    val currentHeight = it.descent - it.ascent
                    val targetHeight = lineRatio * currentHeight

                    val heightMargin = (targetHeight - currentHeight) / 2

                    // Set line height
                    it.descent += heightMargin.roundToInt()
                    it.ascent -= heightMargin.roundToInt()

                    // Set line space
                    it.descent += space
                    it.bottom += space
                }
        }   
}
```

but I've some troubles if I change values for `lineRatio` or `space` :

- `LineHeight` doesn't change
- `LineSpace`, instead of change space with next span, it goes up or down the text inside the current span

**EDIT : SOLUTION**

I've found the problem... First, the code above is working ! The problem came from my selection, I did not select the line entirely (the "\n" at the end)